# Table valued parameters - order of records to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, table-valued-parameters

I have a stored procedure that accepts a table-valued parameter.

I am passing a Datatable from my C# DAL. Are TVPs guaranteed to retain the order of rows when invoking the stored proc. My guess is that it should be (in which case this is a dumb question to ask). But I just want to be dead-sure about it.

Thanks

Vikas

Comment: Do you want the _caller_ to determine the order or do you intend to _require_ an order?  If the latter then you could just order the TVP in the sproc.  Why does the order matter?

Comment: Let me clarify; There is already an interface between the C# code and sproc of TVPs that allows sending a List of records.In a specific case,I need to send just 2 records(as of now only 2; going further it might be more) with the caveat that the 2 records should be saved in order.i want to reuse this interface - hence want to make sure that the order does not get scrambled when invoking the sproc using TVP.

Comment: can't you just have two columns in your TVP, where one is your sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order should be preserved.

From [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx):

> Table-valued parameters offer more flexibility and in some cases
>   better performance than temporary tables or other ways to pass a list
>   of parameters. Table-valued parameters offer the following benefits:
>
> - Do not acquire locks for the initial population of data from a client.
> - Provide a simple programming model.
> - Enable you to include complex business logic in a single routine.
> - Reduce round trips to the server.
> - Can have a table structure of different cardinality.
> - Are strongly typed.
> - **Enable the client to specify sort order and unique keys.**

Comment: I read the documentation to state that the _client_ specifies the sort order, thus the server does not change it.

Comment: I'm not sure if "enables the client to specify sort order" means that it retains the order in which the values were. Maybe it just means that you _could_ specify it, f.e. by adding a sort-column to the type, provide it and sort by that column. Actually i also need to know if the order is guaranteed.